# How to select until sum a column reaches a value?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i need to select records from a mysql table until sum a column reaches a goal value,
lets assume my table is that

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key,
     Date DateTime,
     type int, 
     MyAmountCol int
    );

INSERT INTO Table1
(Date, type, MyAmountCol)
VALUES
('2013-02-01 00:00:00','85482','1'),
('2013-02-01 00:00:00','47228','2'),
('2013-02-02 00:00:00','12026','4'),
('2013-02-03 00:00:00','78927','6'),
('2013-02-04 00:00:00','85662','2'),
('2013-03-05 00:00:00','47978','1'),
('2013-08-07 00:00:00','8582','1');
```

and this is the sql query i am trying .

```
SELECT
  O.Id,
  O.Type,
  O.MyAmountCol,
  (SELECT
     sum(MyAmountCol) FROM Table1
   WHERE Id <= O.Id) 'RunningTotal'
FROM Table1 O
HAVING RunningTotal <=8
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec160/5

but doesn't work as needed,Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want instead? i replaced your total with session variable and it comes to the same conclusion.

Comment: @AryaSame . . . Your code looks to be doing what you want.  What is the issue?

Comment: I would do it the way [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244418/9092099) suggests

Comment: @GordonLinoff my code doesn't what i want,i want it bring the records until RunningTotal is bigger or equal than 8, i want it bring only 2 records which MyAmountCol is 6 and 2 not something else.

Comment: @AryaSame . . . I would suggest you ask a new question and strive to explain the logic.  Your code is producing a running total -- just as you are asking for.  It is based on the insertion order of the rows -- which is very sensible.  What is not understood is what you really want.  Starting over with a new question is probably the best approach.

Comment: What version?  10.2 and 8.0 have "windowing functions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+ and the more recent versions of MySQL, you can use window functions:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             sum(t1.amount) over (order by t1.id) as running_amount
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where running_amount <= 8
```

If you want the first that *reaches or exceeds* 8, then:

```
where running_amount - amount < 8
```

In older versions, you can do this with a correlated subquery or variables:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             (select sum(tt1.amount)
              from table1 tt1
              where tt1.id <= t1.id
             ) as running_amount
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where running_amount <= 8;
```

I prefer the subquery to the `having` clause, but that is just a preference.

Answer (score 0):

DO it like this:

```
;with cte as
(
select *, 
sum(MyAmountCol) over(order by id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as RunningTotal from Table1
)
select * from cte where RunningTotal <= 8
```

Comment: what i have is,Server version: 10.1.10-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution,it doesn't support your query,should i install mysql 8 instead of this?

Comment: thought is was mysql as tagged

Comment: i thought everything is possible on mariadb that you can with mysql